# Symfony 3 - VichUploader Serving files with a controller

Tags: php, file, symfony, controller

I use Symfony 3.4 with PHP 5.6.

I want to use the vichuploader Bundle to download files. I managed to make it work normally. But now I want to be able to use the files directly from the controller to be able to use them in my database. After reading the documentation, I tried to do something.

I have on my **index.html.twig** the line :

```
<td><a href="{{ path('paquet_file', { 'id': uneInfo.id}) }}"</a>{{ uneInfo.urlPaquet }} </td>
```

On my **controller** :

```
namespace Site\PagesBundle\Controller;

use Site\PagesBundle\Entity\Paquet;
use Site\PagesBundle\Entity\TypeUser;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Handler\DownloadHandler;

//........


     /** 
     * Serves an uploaded file.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}/file", name="paquet_file")
     */
    public function fileAction(Paquet $paquet)
    {   
        $downloadHandler = $this->get('vich_uploader.download_handler');

        return $downloadHandler->downloadObject($paquet, $fileField = 'paquetFile', Paquet::class, true);
    }
```

**My entity :**

```
<?php

namespace Site\PagesBundle\Entity;

use DateTimeImmutable;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Site\PagesBundle\Entity\Paquet;
use Site\PagesBundle\Entity\TypeUser;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

/**
 * Paquet
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="paquet")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Site\PagesBundle\Repository\PaquetRepository")
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class Paquet
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;


    /**  
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="TypeUser")  
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="Packages_des_TypesUser") 
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */  
    private $typeUser;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->typeUser = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /** 
     * Get TypeUser 
     * 
     * @return Site\PagesBundle\Entity\TypeUser 
     */ 
    public function getTypeUser() 
    { 
        return $this->typeUser; 
    }

    public function deleteTypeFromTypesUser(TypeUser $type)
    {
        $this->typeUser->removeElement($type);
    }



    /**
     * Set typeUser
     *
     * @param Site\PagesBundle\Entity\TypeUser $typeUser
     *
     * @return Paquet
     */
    public function setTypeUser(Site\PagesBundle\Entity\TypeUser $typeUser)
    {
        $this->typeUser = $typeUser;

        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="titre", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $titre;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="urlPaquet", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $urlPaquet;

    /**
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="paquet", fileNameProperty="urlPaquet")
     * @var File
     */
    private $paquetFile;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     *
     * @var \DateTime
    */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
 * @param File|UploadedFile $unPaquetFile
 *
 * @return Paquet
*/
public function setPaquetFile(File $unPaquetFile = null)
{
    $this->paquetFile = $unPaquetFile;

    if ($unPaquetFile) 
    {
        $this->updatedAt = new \DateTimeImmutable();
    }


    return $this;
}

    /**
     * Set updatedAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $updatedAt
     *
     * @return Paquet
     */
    public function setUpdatedAt($updatedAt)
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updatedAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUpdatedAt()
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

/**
 * @return File|null
 */
public function getPaquetFile()
{
    return $this->paquetFile;
}


    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="urlNotice", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $urlNotice;

    /**
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="notice", fileNameProperty="urlNotice")
     * @var File
     */
    private $noticeFile;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="commentaire", type="text")
     */
    private $commentaire;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set titre
     *
     * @param string $titre
     *
     * @return Paquet
     */
    public function setTitre($titre)
    {
        $this->titre = $titre;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get titre
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitre()
    {
        return $this->titre;
    }

    /**
     * Set urlPaquet
     *
     * @param string $urlPaquet
     *
     * @return Paquet
     */
    public function setUrlPaquet($urlPaquet)
    {
        $this->urlPaquet = $urlPaquet;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get urlPaquet
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getUrlPaquet()
    {
        return $this->urlPaquet;
    }

    /**
     * @return File|null
     */
    public function getNoticeFile()
    {
        return $this->noticeFile;
    }

        /**
     * @param File|UploadedFile $uneNoticeFile
     *
     * @return Paquet
    */
    public function setNoticeFile(File $uneNoticeFile = null)
    {
        $this->noticeFile = $uneNoticeFile;

        if ($uneNoticeFile) 
        {
            $this->updatedAt = new \DateTimeImmutable();
        }


        return $this;
}

    /**
     * Set urlNotice
     *
     * @param string $urlNotice
     *
     * @return Paquet
     */
    public function setUrlNotice($urlNotice)
    {
        $this->urlNotice = $urlNotice;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get urlNotice
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUrlNotice()
    {
        return $this->urlNotice;
    }

    /**
     * Set commentaire
     *
     * @param string $commentaire
     *
     * @return Paquet
     */
    public function setCommentaire($commentaire)
    {
        $this->commentaire = $commentaire;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get commentaire
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCommentaire()
    {
        return $this->commentaire;
    }
}
```

But when I click on the URL file :

[Screen - My page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThLwj.png)

I have this file :

[Screen - Downloaded file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqpJB.png)

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use this bundle yet (I plan to work with it soon though).
But from what I see in the doc page : https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/downloads/serving_files_with_a_controller.md the 4th  argument is the filename while you set true to it.

So maybe it's just a filename issue ? You could try to set filename to null (I guess it will take the real filename by default) or set your own filename (with extension) as the 4th argument in the `downloadObject()` call.

Comment: Omg, you are the best ... In theory, by setting it to true, it had to default to the correct file name. I even contacted the creator of the bundle and he himself did not understand and did not know what to do. You are a genius

Comment: You're welcome. Maybe report to the author the fact that setttng the filename to true cause an issue then, so it could fix it. but, IMHO, it's normal to have an error when the set a wrong argument, it could at least add an error message to inform the parameter is not good.

Comment: Yes I reported the error. And indeed, it is a pity that he did not take into account this kind of error in view of the reputation of his bundle